# Pass information into jQuery ajax response handling function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Assuming I am doing this:

```
$.get("/api/GetComments?post=" + post, function(data) {
    var a = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log("comments=" + a.count);
});
```

However, when I do the `.get`, I need to make available meta data about the request, that the response handling function can access (without having to pass it to and from the server) i.e. something like this?

```
$.get("/api/GetComments?post=" + post, function(data, id_of_div_to_update) {
    var a = JSON.parse(data);
    $("div[id=" + id_of_div_to_update + "]").text(a);
});
```

Comment: `id_of_div_to_update` is the html attribute id of DOM element ? I mean not a value from server ?

Comment: you can do like `var callback = (function( id ){ return function( data ){  // here u get id and data };})( id_of_div_to_update);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there is no need in this as Your ajax call live in the closure (function) scope and this means it know (You define any data You need) about some additional data You need for visualizing callback data:

```
// ...
(function(){
    // ...
    var id_of_div_to_update = '#output';
    // ...
    $.get("/api/GetComments?post=" + post, function(data) {
        var a = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log("comments=" + a.count);
        console.log("div_to_update=" + id_of_div_to_update);
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

well first you can pass the data as object which is more clear and readable, instead of passing it in url .. **use getJOSN to get the response as json** which includes the id of div you need to update

```
$.getJSON(url, {"post":post},function(data) {
    console.log("comments=" + data.count);
    console.log("div_to_update=" + data.id_of_div_to_update);
}
```

your response should be like

```
{"count":1,"id":12}
```

**updated**

since i assume you already know the id of div to update you can set it into a variable and use it later

```
 var id_of_div_to_update="something";
$.getJSON(url, {"post":post},function(data) {
    console.log("comments=" + data.count);
    console.log("div_to_update=" + id_of_div_to_update);
}
```

Comment: I want to avoid having to pass strings the server doesnt need to know about into and back out from the server

Comment: You may have mis understood my question, sorry. I updated it to reflect a little more clearly what I meant. The other guy answered correctly first. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add a callback function in AJAX that get executed after the success or failure of the get request. For example

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: function(response){
    console.log(response)
    // process  
  },
});
```

If your jQuery version is above 1.8, you should use 'done', 'fail' and 'always' callbacks.
More information can be found at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/.